# How to decrypt using crypto-js with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I have an encrypted code snippet, which I would like to decrypt by using `crypto-js`. Below I've tried to convert it w/o success. I dont see any response, any idea what is a correct way to decrypt?

this is my code:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
const encryptedValue = "MIIBCAQEAuPFrd+xVq/ciJKo5xQjL8KHtaDA/IHgWMuaeg2rB9FptbUa+nE7Qx9TL2HLaTDQvF" 

private decryptStr(args): string {
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.decrypt(args, {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return  console.log('EncryptMethod',  decrypted);
    }

this.decryptStr(encryptedValue);
```

Comment: I think that you have to provide in which way you encrypt the string, we cannot help you now (e.g. if is sha256 you can't decrypt).